# find scalar product of vectors in rectangular

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, inner-products

let us consider following problem and picture

[image]

we have $ABCD$ rectagular with $AB=3$ and $BC=5$,$F$ and  $E$ are midpoints of  rectangular  sides,we should find scalar product of

[image]

my question is  can i locate  point  $A$ arbitrary or could i take  coordinates of points arbitrary so that satisfy length  property,namely  $AB=3$,$BC=5$ or?clearly it seems that  angle  $FEC$  are not  orthogonal,but how can i proof it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Chasles relation we have
$$\vec{EF}\cdot\vec{EC}=(\vec{EA}+\vec{AF})\cdot(\vec{ED}+\vec{DC})=\vec{EA}\cdot\vec{ED}+\vec{AF}\cdot\vec{DC}\\
=-\frac{1}{4}(BC)^2+\frac{1}{2}(AB)^2=-\frac{7}{4}$$

Comment: we have  $-7/4$  as one possible  answer among multiple choices ,please  see this http://www.naec.ge/images/doc/MASC_SERT/matematika_ped_test_2013.pdf   with number $19$

Comment: Yes the correct answer is $-\frac{7}{4}$

Comment: correct  here it is http://www.naec.ge/images/doc/EXAMS/math_ped_2013_pasuxebi_web.pdf

Comment: Sorry but you give me a paper with strange (for me) language:)

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: sorry  on first page there is  number of  problems with correct  answers.for example problem number  $19$  has correct answer as  g(გ)

Comment: by the way it is georgian.see please https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgian_language

Comment: my native language

Comment: @dato Ok but  if you have a question please translate it in english.

Comment: yes yes i have to translate.this question is translated.of course there  is no doubt about it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if point $E$ and $F$  and $C$ are translated by $X$ then the vectors are $(F+X)-(E+X)=F-E$ and $(C+X)-(E+X)=C-E$, the same as if no translation.

Even more, you can also apply any rotation. They are transformations that preserve the scalar product.

Comment: so for example take $A$ as origin  $A(0,0)$ and  $B(0,3)$

Comment: Yes, the origin can be placed in $A$. If it were not in $A$ you can move it there by a translation and that doesn't change the scalar product. Then, rotating, $B$ can be moved there if it wasn't to begin with.